# Error in solve.default(var(x)) - R

Tags: r

Venho tentando construir um mapa de distribuição para determinadas espécies usando métodos de distância. Estou tendo dificuldades em obter resultado via Distância de Mahalanobis. O pacote que dispõe desta função é o `dismo`, a qual, é expressa como `mahal`.
Ao entrar com os dados o console me retorna que:

```
Error in solve.default(var(x)) : 
sistema é computacionalmente singular: condição recíproca número = 3.14572e-20
```

Pesquisando, encontrei informações de que o erro ocorre quando a matriz não pode ser invertida, e/ou com quando valor de covariância é próximo de zero. Entretanto não encontro uma maneira de solucionar este problema. Procurei entender o problema, e gostaria de saber se existem manipulações matemáticas para contornar o erro?

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Segue uma amostra dos dados.

```
head na matrix:
alt bio1 bio5 bio6 bio7 bio9 bio10 bio12 bio18 bio19 footprint luzworld
1  51  275  395  178  217  284   326    40     4     2  14.00000        0
2  15  277  396  181  215  285   327    42     4     2  14.00000        0
3 136  270  390  172  218  280   321    39     5     2  12.04751        0
4  94  273  393  175  218  282   324    40     5     2  14.06253        0
5  52  275  395  178  217  284   326    40     3     2  14.00000        0
6 245  265  385  165  220  275   316    39     6     2   7.00000        0
```

Comment: tem alguma variável que é constante? tipo essa luzworld?

Comment: consegue adicionar o resultado de `det(cov(seu_banco))` na pergunta? Uma matriz é invertível se e somente se esse determinante for != 0. Como esse problema é bem específico dos seus dados, fica diícil ajudar sem ter o conjunto de dados completo.

Comment: Nenhuma variável constante, embora luzworld apresente muitos zeros. Tentei calcular a distancia de Mahalanobis retirando as variáveis footprint e luzworld, o erro permanece. 
O determinante da matriz é muito próximo de zero, será esse o problema?
  



                    det(cov(nativo))
                    [1] -6.938182e+20

Comment: Na verdade `det(cov(nativo))`, -6.938182e+20 é muito negativo no seu caso, o que é estranho uma vez que o determinaante da matriz de covariancias deveria ser sempre positivo. (veja aqui http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889425/what-does-determinant-of-covariance-matrix-give). O problema está por aí...

Comment: Consegue postar a matriz de covariância?

Comment: Fez imputação de dados? algumas vezes isso pode originar um determinante negativo.